# why overlay layout does not work on the system settings app?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-developer-api

I'm currently facing an issue where the overlay layout fails to appear upon launching the system settings app. The intended functionality is reminiscent of an app lock feature: upon tapping the settings app, an overlay layout should activate, requesting a pattern input to initiate the unlocking process. However, I'm unable to achieve this behavior successfully.

After successfully granting permission for the top app overlay. The desired behavior is similar to an app lock functionality, where upon clicking the settings app, an overlay layout should appear asking for a pattern to unlock.

While my overlay layouts work seamlessly in various apps, they don't seem to function as intended in the system settings app, particularly on Android versions above 10.

```
private fun CheckOverlayPermission() {
    // Choose a request code

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M && !Settings.canDrawOverlays(this)) {
        // If the permission is not granted, open the overlay permission settings
        val intent = Intent(
            Settings.ACTION_MANAGE_OVERLAY_PERMISSION,
            Uri.parse("package:$packageName")
        )
        startActivityForResult(intent, overlayPermissionCode)
    } else {
        // Permission is already granted or not needed on this version
        // Your overlay logic here
    }

}
// this function to to check the package name if exist in the 
database and show the overlay layout 

private fun onAppForeground(foregroundAppPackage: String) {

    hideOverlay()

    //UnInstall Application............

    //Lock overlay work
    if (lockedAppPackageSet.contains(foregroundAppPackage)) {
        if (appLockerPreferences.getFingerPrintEnabled() || PermissionChecker.checkOverlayPermission(
                applicationContext
            ).not()
        ) {
            val intent =
                OverlayValidationActivity.newIntent(applicationContext, foregroundAppPackage)
            if (lastForegroundAppPackage == applicationContext.packageName) {
                intent.flags = Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK
            } else {
                intent.flags = Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK or Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK
            }

            startActivity(intent)

        } else {
            showOverlay(foregroundAppPackage)
        }
    }
    lastForegroundAppPackage = foregroundAppPackage
}

// show overlay layout 

private fun showOverlay(lockedAppPackageName: String) {
    if (isOverlayShowing.not()) {
        isOverlayShowing = true
        overlayView.setHiddenDrawingMode(appLockerPreferences.getHiddenDrawingMode())
        overlayView.setAppPackageName(lockedAppPackageName)
        windowManager.addView(overlayView, overlayParams);
    }
}

// forground observer to checks the locked apps


//         for above 10 or 11

    private fun getForegroundObservableaboveQ(): Flowable<String>? {
        return Flowable.interval(0, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
            .filter { PermissionChecker.checkUsageAccessPermission(context) }
            .map {
                val mUsageStatsManager =
                    context.getSystemService(Service.USAGE_STATS_SERVICE) as UsageStatsManager
                val time = System.currentTimeMillis()

                val usageEvents =
                    mUsageStatsManager.queryUsageStats(INTERVAL_DAILY, time - 10000, time)
                val sortedUsageEvents = usageEvents.sortedBy { it.lastTimeUsed }
                val usageEvent = sortedUsageEvents.lastOrNull()

                UsageEventWrapper(usageEvent)
            }
            .filter { it.usageEvent != null }
            .map { it.usageEvent }
            .filter { it.packageName != null }
            .map { it.packageName }
            .distinctUntilChanged()
    }

// overlay layouts params


object OverlayViewLayoutParams {

    fun get(): WindowManager.LayoutParams {
        val layoutFlag: Int = if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_APPLICATION_OVERLAY
        } else {
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_PHONE
        }


        return WindowManager.LayoutParams(
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                layoutFlag,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_WATCH_OUTSIDE_TOUCH or
                        WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_IN_SCREEN or
                        WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL or

                        WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE,
                PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT
            )
    }
}
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: code added. please help.;